# How to document (javadoc) a message handler method?

Tags: android, javadoc, handler

I have a class which implements [Handler.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.Callback.html)

So, in my code i have something like this :

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    switch (msg.what)
    {
        case ThreadMessages.MSG_1:
        {
            break;
        }

        case ThreadMessages.MSG_2:
        {
            break;
        }

        case ThreadMessages.MSG_3:
        {
            break;
        }

        case ThreadMessages.MSG_4:
        {
            break;
        }

        case ThreadMessages.MSG_5:
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

How should i comment this method to reflect the messages that my class can handle ?

The purpose here , is to let a developer know what message he can send to the class without having to read the source code , just using the java doc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## My Advice:

In class `ThreadMessages` Rename `MSG_1` and the other static fields to some meaningful names.

Above your `handleMessage`

Add the following comments:

```
/**
 * Can handle {@link ThreadMessages#MSG_1}, {@link ThreadMessages#MSG_2}, {@link ThreadMessages#MSG_3}, {@link ThreadMessages#MSG_4}, and {@link ThreadMessages#MSG_5}
 */
```

And in class `ThreadMessages`

Explain each static feild by adding above it

```
/**
 * this is used for
 */
```

Comment: The MSG_X name stands for the example , my static field are ofcourse well named. Anyway , @link seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle has a great document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format) about how to comment your code so you can generate Java Docs later on.

Comment: Yes, Sun wrote it back in 2004; but, he's asking for a specific way to markup his code, for his situation.